# Prevent redirect from triggering App / Universal Link behavior

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

We have a web product and Android/iOS mobile apps with App (Android) & Universal (iOS) links enabled. This enables the OS to open our app in various scenarios where the user would otherwise have been navigated to our mobile web product.

We are now facing a problem where our apps open under this undesirable scenario:

- User opens the native browser and navigates to `https://www.example.com`. In this case, the OS respects the user's intention to use the native browser and does not open the app.
- User taps on "Login" on our web site. This sends the user to `https://login.example.com` where they submit their credentials.
- `https://login.example.com` redirects the user to `https://www.example.com`. At this point, both Android & iOS open the app.

It would be preferable for the redirection to occur within the browser so as to continue respecting the user's intent. I believe this happens due to the redirection from a non-app/universal link domain to an app/universal link domain.

Is there a way to perform this redirection without leading to the apps getting opened? I've tried redirecting via a `Location` header, and via a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='https://www.example.com'"/>` head tag with the same result. The only remaining thing to try I can see is to host our login feature under the `www` subdomain.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No, we haven't yet.

Comment: @siger 
The simple workaround is to move the login to be on the same subdomain, e.g. https://www.example.com/login

Answer (score 0):

As a user, you can solve this problem by "Disabling Instant Apps" on your phone.

To opt-out of Instant Apps go into your Settings > Google > Settings for Google Apps > Google Play Instant > switch toggle to OFF.